# Image is not showing inside javascript html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, variables

I'm trying to show cards from my MySQL, array are working very well... but pictures don't.
I'm pretty sure that there is an error in my code.

I'm blocked on it for 2 hours. I don't know how to do show correctly.

Here the part of my code. If you need more details, can you ask me?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        $.getJSON('http://192.168.1.53/dbconfig.php?lat='+ position.coords.latitude +'&lng='+ position.coords.longitude, function(result){
            $.each(result.lieux, function(i, field){
            var photo = "http://192.168.1.53/test.php?id=3";
var html = [
        '<div href="#" class="store-card-item">',
        '<em class="bg-red-dark">150 <u> mètres</u></em>',
        '<img class="responsive-image preload-image" data-original="' + photo + '" alt="img">',
        '<h3>'+ field.nom +'</h3>',
        '<a href="#" class="store-card-cart"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i></a>',
        '<a href="#" class="store-card-heart"><i class="fa fa-star color-yellow-dark"></i><i class="fa fa-star color-yellow-dark"></i></a>',
        '</div>'
].join('');

var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('class', 'post block bc2');
    div.innerHTML = html;
    document.getElementById('posts').appendChild(div);
            });
        });
});
});
</script>
<div id="posts"></div>
```

Thank you for your help.
Alex

Comment: where is src for an img tag?

Comment: I don't see the img tag. Maybe It is the problem...

Comment: I 'm using data-original= instead of src.

Comment: You are using `data-original` attribute for img. If my understanding is right you are using lazyload plugin. I don't see the lazyload code here and that is the problem. May be you can change the `data-original` attribute to `src` and it will work as of the moment.

Comment: Yes. I'm using lazyload. `data-original` is working very well outside the JS script.

Comment: If you are using a lazy loader, It maybe querying all the elements that have the attribute data-original but because that part of the html is appended dinamically after an AJAX request, at the moment the lazy loader get all images to load that part does not exist.

Comment: Ok thank you, should I use src?